# Break Action method into multiple functions?

Tags: java, oop, configuration, struts2

I have an `Action` class with methods which are mapped to individual actions. However, since some methods are long I want to break them into functions.

So if `Action1`--->`method1`, I want `method1` to be like:

```
method1(){  
  // do something
  f1();
  f2();
}
```

where `f1` and `f2` are functions doing small things.

I want to break it for *readability*.

Can I do this *like* keep `f1`, `f2` in my action class and not mapped to actions?

And I want to do the same in my `Bean`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, and should do this. Java code is Java code. Whether it's a Struts action or anything else doesn't change how Java works.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a few non-`public` methods in the action class which you don't map to actions.

But if you want to call this methods from other beans, then you might want to make it `public` and thus it will be accessible indirectly via [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation), unless you configure to exclude those methods from invocation.

Struts action classes should be simple and laconic and contain only a logic of the presentation layer.

Business logic should move to the service layer.